# Why did Hera tell Dryope to kidnap Hylas?

Tags: greek, hera, nymphs

I found a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryope) with a number of Dryope from Greek Mythology. One of them says a nymph (possibly a different one from my last question) of the name was told by Hera to kidnap Hylas. On the [Hylas page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylas), it makes no mention of Dryope.

Comment: Dryope _is_ mentioned in the [Hylas Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylas#Argonauts): "Heracles took Hylas with him on the Argo, making him one of the Argonauts. Hylas was kidnapped by nymphs of the spring of Pegae, Dryope, that fell in love with him in Mysia and vanished without a trace (Apollonios Rhodios)"

Answer (score 1):

Hylas was beloved by Hercules, which is likely reason enough for Hera to have him kidnapped.  https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Hylas